# Image of the projection map onto an irreducible module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra $V$ be an $A$-module.Let $V=\bigoplus W_j$ with $W_j$ irreducible for all j .Let $M$ be an irreducible $A$-module. And $N=\Sigma \{W_i: W_i$ is isomorphic to $M\}$. Now let $\pi_i$ be projection map of $V$ onto $W_i$. Let $W \subset V$, and , $W$ isomorphic to $M$ therefore to $W_i$. Why is $\pi_i(W)=W_i$ or $0$? Also why is $W \subset \Sigma \pi_j (W)$ where $W_j$ is isomorphic to $M$ present in the above direct sum and $\pi_j$ the projection map of $W_j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\pi_i(W)\subseteq W_i$ and $W_i$ is irreducible, so  $\pi_i(W)= W_i$ or $0$. Further, $W\cong M$, hence $W \subset \Sigma \pi_j (W)$.

Comment: Why can't $\pi_j(W)=0$ for all j?

Comment: Since $\sum_j \pi_j = {\rm id}$.

Comment: The image pf $\Sigma \pi_j$ is $N$ which may not be equal $V$ . We are considering only those $j$'s in the where $W_j \cong M$. Not all $W_i$ in the direct sum are congruent to $M$.

Comment: I consider ${\bf all}$ $j$. If $W_j\not\cong M$ then of course $\pi_j(W)=0$. But $\sum_j \pi_j = {\rm id}$, so $\pi_j(W)\ne 0$ for some $j$.